# how can i get a ASP.NET session variable in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

i have a website a with some textfields.

website b is in the iframe of a.

I saved in website b some values  in different sessions

```
  Session("anzahlInterneTeilnehmer") = anzahlInterneTeilnehmer
  Session("anzahlExterneTeilnehmer") = anzahlExterneTeilnehmer
```

after i saved the sessions i call the parent function from website a

```
parent.parentTeilnehmer()
```

i want to display the session values in the textfields of website a

```
            function parentTeilnehmer() {
            var intern = ????
            var extern = ????
            var InterneTextFeld = ISGetObject("WebInput1");
            var ExterneTextFeld = ISGetObject("WebInput2");
            InterneTextFeld.SetValueData(intern);
            ExterneTextFeld.SetValueData(extern);
        }
```

how can i do that without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access ASP.NET session variable from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555454/access-asp-net-session-variable-from-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access ASP.NET session variable from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555454/access-asp-net-session-variable-from-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Session is stored server side so you cannot access these variables clientside via javascript. I suggest saving these variables to a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="anzahlInterneTeilnehmer" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="anzahlExterneTeilnehmer" runat="server" />
```

Attach an event handler to the Website A's page PreRender method and in there set the
anzahlInterneTeilnehmer's value to the session value (excuse my VB)

```
Private Sub Page_Render(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreRender
anzahlInterneTeilnehmer.Value = Session("anzahlInterneTeilnehmer")
End Sub
```

Then in your javascript

```
var internHolder = document.getElementById("anzahlInterneTeilnehmer");
var intern = internHolder.value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this in javascript

```
var val = <%= Session["MyVariable"]%>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access Session variables in javascript only if your js function is present on *.aspx* page which is not a good approach as it is better to keep our script files in separate Scripts folder so you can store session values in hidden fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSessionValues() {
        var intern = '<%=Session("InternalValue") %>';
        var extern = '<%=Session("ExternalValue") %>';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It works for me if I set _Session("InternalValue")_ and _Session("ExternalValue")_ at _Page_Load_ event, how you do that ?